# Python Serverless Function Vercel - Next.js

Tags: python, next.js, serverless, vercel

I found out that I could use Python to create a serverless function inside a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started) project. Once deployed to [Vercel](https://vercel.com/), it will get converted into a serverless function.

I went through the docs and found a [simple example](https://vercel.com/docs/serverless-functions/supported-languages#python) that outputs the date:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from datetime import datetime

class handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

  def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/plain')
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write(str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).encode())
    return
```

They offer a live working example [here](https://python-api.now-examples.now.sh/api/date).

Apparently all that is needed is to place the file `date.py` inside the `api` folder of a bootstrapped Next.js project and you're off to the races. When deployed, Vercel will detect the Python file and serve it as a serverless function.

The deploy succeeded and I placed the file inside the `pages/api` folder as required. However, the function is never picked up (image below):
[image: vercel function output]

Older versions apparently required the [configuration of serverless functions by adding a `vercel.json` file](https://vercel.com/docs/configuration#project/functions). But this doesn't seem necessary now.

What am I missing?

Comment: if you are putting the api folder inside pages folder try moving it outside of it

Comment: @evgenifotia when you generate a new app with [`create-next-app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started) it automatically creates an `api` folder inside `pages`.

Comment: Did you try with flask ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After going over the FAQs. I found an entry named [Unmatched Function Pattern](https://vercel.com/docs/platform/frequently-asked-questions#unmatched-function-pattern), it states:

> the functions property uses a glob pattern for each key. This pattern must match Serverless Function source files within the `api` directory.

It also mentions:

> if you'd like to use a Serverless Function that isn't written with Node.js in combination with Next.js, you can place it in the `api` directory (provided by the platform), since `pages/api` (provided by Next.js) only supports JavaScript.

I think that this needs to be clarified a bit. There is indeed an default `api` folder when you bootstrap a Next.js project with `create-next-app`, but it's created inside the `pages` directory.

If you follow the [example they give](https://vercel.com/docs/serverless-functions/supported-languages#python), you might just go ahead and create a serverless function in a supported language (other than JavaScript) inside the `pages/api` directory and wonder why Vercel doesn't pick it up when you deploy.

In short, if you're using [another language to write a serverless function](https://vercel.com/docs/serverless-functions/supported-languages) inside a Next.js project. Be sure to place it inside an `api` folder that sits in the **root** directory of the project (if there's none, create one).

Thanks to @evgenifotia for the suggestion, it pointed me in the right direction and helped me solve this issue.

**Note**: You can only have a single `api` directory that houses serverless functions. Either you have a `pages/api` directory or a `api` directory in the root folder, having both in a single project is **not** supported.

Comment: In this case will the regular nodejs functions continue to work?

Comment: The Node.js functions will work inside a `api` directory located inside `pages` or outside of it as well.

Comment: Sorry, my goal is to use both nodejs and python functions in one project. Should I just put all of them in parent `api` folder or can I have one `api` and another `pages/api` folder?

Comment: Have a single `api` folder in the root of the project. That way you can use Node.js and Python functions.

Comment: hey @JuanMarco first, thank you your post has been very helpful; what do you change in the next config to remap the api on root/api instead of the default pages/api folder ?

Comment: @Stormsson there should be no changes in the config, just replace `pages/api` with `api` in the root folder of the project.

Comment: I had a chat with Vercel support, and actually reproduced what my issue was; 
It's now possible to have both /root/api for python & /root/pages/api , the important part was to correctly configure vercel.json so that you can have a logic to identify if the request is for python or nextjs; i personally used a prefix and everything sent with /p/ gets routed to py , and the rest is handled by nextjs