# Vercel Serverless Function crashing due to Cannot find module '/var/task/backend/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs'

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, es6-modules, vercel

I have an issue with importing `axios` in Vercel Serverless Functions. The function breaks depending on the way I import axios. I have [created a discussion on vercel](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/discussions/9637), a github [issue](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/9769)  and also created a [reproducible demo repository](https://github.com/cmgchess/vercel-serverless-axios-issue). I find it annoying that I have to switch the way I import axios when I want the function to run locally (dev) and deploy without breaking.
I would like to know if there is a proper solution to this.

| **Endpoint** | **Dev (Node 14.15.1) & (Node 18.15.0)** | **Deploy (Node 18.x)** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://vercel-serverless-axios-issue.vercel.app/api/axios-break | Working | Not working |
| https://vercel-serverless-axios-issue.vercel.app/api/axios-work | Not working | Working |

For [`axios-work`](https://github.com/cmgchess/vercel-serverless-axios-issue/blob/master/api/axios-work.js#L1) I import axios like **`import axios from 'axios/dist/node/axios.cjs';`**
It **works after deploying** but **breaks in dev** giving below error

```bash
Error: Function `api/axios-work.js` failed with exit code 1
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './dist/node/axios.cjs' is not defined by "exports" in E:\vercel-serverless-axios-issue\node_modules\axios\package.json
    at throwExportsNotFound (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:290:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:513:3)
    at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:432:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:472:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename.sharedData.moduleResolveFilenameHook.installedValue [as _resolveFilename] (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vercel\node_modules\@cspotcode\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:811:30)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\vercel-serverless-axios-issue\api\axios-work.js:1:1) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
Error: Function `api/axios-work.js` failed with exit code 1
```

For [`axios-break`](https://github.com/cmgchess/vercel-serverless-axios-issue/blob/master/api/axios-break.js#L1) I import axios like **`import axios from 'axios';`**
It **works in dev** but **breaks after deploying** giving below error

```bash
Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs'
Did you forget to add it to "dependencies" in `package.json`?
RequestId: c1845ce2-d588-4f0a-a478-95bfafacf92b Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: Happening to me too! Did you find a fix?

Comment: @jetlej no i just went with the weird import when deploying and change back in dev when i want. i also asked in their discussion but didn't get an answer

Comment: @jetlej vercel is looking at the [issue](https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/9769#issuecomment-1513744322). hope there will be a resolution

Comment: same here with @vercel/postgres, just change the import in the way he's looking for it and the production works

Comment: @colo https://github.com/cmgchess/vercel-serverless-axios-issue/pull/2 this is how I kinda fixed it. Didn't test with local tho. But production worked